# How get only modification year using batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a problem

i need modification date of file. And i use windows batch script. But i can't get modification date and split them.

i currently using this command

```
for /f %a in ('dir /b') do @echo %a %~ta
```

result

```
file89401.txt 06/18/2005 05:37 AM
file8941.txt 11/21/2000 03:48 PM
file89411.txt 09/02/2008 02:14 PM
file89421.txt 03/01/2012 02:06 PM
file89431.txt 10/23/2001 06:48 AM
file89441.txt 10/27/2010 10:21 AM
file89451.txt 11/11/2011 05:40 AM
file89461.txt 11/23/2000 02:48 AM
file89471.txt 10/10/2001 01:28 AM
file89481.txt 07/14/2000 10:17 AM
file89491.txt 02/21/2004 10:24 PM
file89501.txt 03/12/2011 09:42 AM
file8951.txt 09/26/2003 11:31 PM
file89511.txt 08/17/2001 02:31 AM
file89521.txt 01/01/2004 01:11 PM
```

and i need only modification date and following format

```
2005/06/18
2000/1/21
2008/09/02
2012/03/01
2001/10/23
2010/10/27
2011/11/11
2000/11/23
2001/10/10
2000/07/14
2004/02/21
2011/03/12
2003/9/26
2001/08/17
2004/01/01
```

please help me,, sorry my bad English :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want to see modified date of files under directory **C:\Users\test** in format **yyyy/mm/dd**, below works perfectly for you:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for %%F in ("C:\Users\test\*") do (
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=/ " %%A in ("%%~tF") do (
echo %%C/%%A/%%B
   )
 )
```

**Result:**

```
2013/12/21
2013/11/19
2012/12/28
2012/10/25
2011/10/25
2011/11/09
2010/12/21
```

Answer (score 0):

findstr can only output Date/Time, not Date only.
You can fix it with some code or use a command that does what you want:

```
forfiles /c "cmd /c echo @fdate"
```

this is not a well knwon command, but it does give you the dates.
For more info see `forfiles /?`

to format the date to the desired format use:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=." %%a in (' forfiles /m *.* /c "cmd /c echo @fdate" ') do echo %%c/%%b/%%a
```

(Attention, this is language-dependent This line is for german format ("25.12.2013")
For your format `echo %%c/%%a/%%b` should do the trick)

**EDIT**
just noticed, you want no leading zero on day or month.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=." %%a in (' forfiles /m *.* /c "cmd /c echo @fdate" ') do (
  set dat=%%c/%%a/%%b
  set dat=!dat:/0=/!
  REM replaced "/0" with "/"
  echo %!dat!
)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the prompt,

```dos
for %a in (*.*) do @for /f "delims=/ " %i in ("%~ta") do @echo %k/%i/%j
```

should deliver the goods.

As a batch file,

```dos
@echo off
for %%a in (*.*) do for /f "delims=/ " %%i in ("%%~ta") do echo %%k/%%i/%%j
```